# Laravel relationship-relationship orderby

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, relationship

I have a Project model which has a ProjcetType hasMany relationship and that ProjectType model has a ProjectTypeOrder hasOne relationship. Now I want to get all the Projects with ProjectTypes ordering the project types by its ProjectTypesOrder 'order' column.

I only has this:

```
Project::with(['images', 'types.order'])->get();
```

(also I am including images)

Before this point I did not have to order the types, now I have to.

How can I do this?

Comment: Any particular reasons you don’t just define the project type order on the ProjectType model? Doing so would be simpler and avoid superfluous joins.

Comment: You are right! I didnt know until now that I can add a single column to the existing table without losing data in laravel..